# how to read comments in html dom body in selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

I want to read the comment below in html dom body using selenium

```
<html>
<head class=.....>
<body>
<script>...</script>
<!--
Campaign Name: POC_SITE_MONETIZATION_DEALS_QA
Experience Name: SMBelow - jQuery Move w/ Tracking
-->
```

I have tried the below two approach:

1)

```
String injectedCampaign =  WebDriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(By.tagName("body")).getAttribute("InnerHTML");
```

2)

```
WebElement ele=WebDriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(By.tagName("body"));
Object attr = ((JavascriptExecutor)WebDriverManager.getWebDriver()).executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes);", ele);
```

Comment: Is the _HTML_ you have provided, the actual _HTML_ the actual _HTML_ or you have cropped it for simplicity?

Comment: It's actual HTML snnipets just content in script and head tag is not shown

Comment: The parent tag and the contents in script are manadtory. Please consider updating the question

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
public static String printCommentedString(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {

        return (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0].childNodes)\n" + 
                "    .filter(function(e) {\n" + 
                "        return e.nodeType === 8\n" + 
                "    })\n" + 
                "    .map(function(e) {\n" + 
                "        return e.nodeValue.trim()\n" + 
                "    })\n" + 
                "    .join('\\n');", element);
    }
```

and then in test case:

```
        WebElement bodyElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body"));
        System.out.println(printCommentedString(driver, bodyElement));
```

You will get your desired result.