# VBA Selenium: How to Extract <!-- p> non-displayed comment text, from a Web Page Element

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, getelementsbytagname

[image: from web page HTML]

I am doing a county property survey. The mailing address is included on each record/webpage as a non-displayed comment <!-- p> with a p tag I am trying to extract those non non-displayed comments which contain the mailing and physical address of the property (see attached jpeg)

I have tried various forms of comment and attribute schemes to add on to the CSS and xPath Selectors for the h2 header above the comments - but no go so far

Set Mailing = MyBrowser.FindElementsByCss("#lxT413 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > h2)
Set Mailing = MyBrowser.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id="lxT413"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/h2")

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!!!

Set Mailing = MyBrowser.FindElementByCss("#lxT413 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td")

Debug.Print Mailing.Attribute("outerHTML")

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020843/how-to-read-comments-in-html-dom-body-in-selenium). Also looking at the screenshot you've provided, it seems that the commented portion of the DOM is not inside the `h2` element but rather inside the `td` element, maybe that is the reason why you can't reach it?

Comment: Using td - when iIRight mouse click the td element and select "Copy Outer HTML"  I get absolutely everything I need, 100%.   But in code when ti try to translate that to the td element by element.text  I get nothing:   Set Mailing = MyBrowser.FindElementByCss("#lxT413 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td")    Debug.Print Mailing.text

Comment: I got it!!!

Set Mailing = MyBrowser.FindElementByCss("#lxT413 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td")

Debug.Print Mailing.Attribute("outerHTML")